# How do I bring my sub menu up closer to my main menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

​I am working on a project for a client and they wanted their logo and menu on two different lines and centered on the page. I have changed the css coding to make that happen, however now when I place the cursor over the "Models" menu the sub menu is about 100px lower than it should be. I have tried everything I can think of to try and figure out what is causing it to drop that far down and I'm throwing in the towel and hitting the message boards.

This is a SuperFish menu, but came as a package for the wordpress template I purchased....

I have outlined the header container (orange), overall navigation container (red) and navigation wrapper (green).

http://maulesite.juvamarketing.com/

HTML CODE

```
<div class="navigation-wrapper"><div class="gdl-current-menu" ></div><div id="main-superfish-wrapper" class="menu-wrapper"><ul id="menu-menu-2" class="sf-menu">    
<li id="menu-item-148" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://mauleairinc.com/maule-air-technical-manuals-and-documents/"><i class="gdl-menu-icon icon-wrench" ></i><span class="gdl-des-prepend"><span class="gdl-label">Support</span></span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-277" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://mauleairinc.com/flight-manuals/"><span class="gdl-sub-label">Flight Manuals</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-276" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://mauleairinc.com/maintenance-manuals/"><span class="gdl-sub-label">Maintenance Manuals</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-278" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://mauleairinc.com/pdf/modification_kit_index.pdf"><span class="gdl-sub-label">Mod Kid Index</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-274" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://mauleairinc.com/service-bulletins/"><span class="gdl-sub-label">Service Bulletins</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-273" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://mauleairinc.com/service-letters/"><span class="gdl-sub-label">Service Letters</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-272" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://mauleairinc.com/supplements/"><span class="gdl-sub-label">Supplements</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-275" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://mauleairinc.com/rel-oel/"><span class="gdl-sub-label">REL &#038; OEL</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul></div><div class="clear"></div>
```

style.css ->

```
/*--- navigation ---*/
/* div.gdl-navigation-wrapper{ position: relative; float: right; } */
div.gdl-navigation-wrapper{ position: relative; text-align: center !important; height: 45px; 
 border: 2px solid red; /* Added for debugging purposes */
}

div.gdl-current-menu { position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; }
div.navigation-wrapper{ display: inline-block; font-family: HelveticaNeue, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   height: 55px; 
   border: 2px solid green; /* Added for debugging purposes */
}

div.responsive-menu-wrapper{ margin: 0px 10px; }
div.responsive-menu-wrapper select{ width: 100%; height: 25px; }
```

superfish.css

```
#main-superfish-wrapper ul li span.gdl-label{ font-size: 15px; line-height: 1.3; display: block; }
#main-superfish-wrapper ul li span.gdl-description{ padding-left: 1px; font-size: 12px; display: block; }
#main-superfish-wrapper .gdl-menu-icon{ float: left; font-size: 14px; line-height: 16px; margin-right: 7px; }
#main-superfish-wrapper .gdl-des-prepend { float: left; }

ul.sf-menu, .sf-menu * { margin: 0, auto; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
ul.sf-menu { line-height: 1; }
ul.sf-menu li { float: left; position: relative;  }
ul.sf-menu li:hover { visibility: inherit; } /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */
ul.sf-menu li a { padding: 0px 20px; line-height: 24px; text-decoration:none; display: block; position: relative; }

/*--- sub menu ---*/
ul.sf-menu li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li.sfHover ul { left: 0; z-index: 101; top: 46px; } /* top: 46px */
ul.sf-menu li ul{ padding-top: -100px;  }
ul.sf-menu li ul li:first-child{ padding-top: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px; 
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px; 
    }
ul.sf-menu li ul li:last-child{ padding-bottom: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px; 
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px; }
ul.sf-menu ul li a{ padding: 5px 0px; margin: 0px 15px; border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; }
ul.sf-menu ul li:first-child > a{ border-top-width: 0px; }
ul.sf-menu li ul ul{ padding-top: 0; }  


ul.sf-menu ul { text-align: left;  }
ul.sf-menu ul { position: absolute; top: 100%; width: 10em; }/* left offset of submenus need to match (see below) */
ul.sf-menu ul li { width: 100%; padding: 0px 0px; }

ul.sf-menu li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li.sfHover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover li ul{ top: 100% }

ul.sf-menu li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li li.sfHover ul { left: 10em; top: -1px; } /* match ul width */

ul.sf-menu li li:last-child{ border: 0px; }
ul.sf-menu li li a{ height: auto; background: none !important; }
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is where the change needs to happen:

```
<ul class="sub-menu" style="float: none;width: 14.5em; display: none;  top: 150px;">
```

Since the code is inline I assume it is being generated with Javascript somewhere. Can you post the JS code that is related to the dropdown menu?

Comment: The ul and li html code is being generated by wordpress. There is no css class handler for .sub-menu or ul.sf-menu ul.sub-menu so I tried putting the style that you suggested in, but it does not bring the sub menu any closer to the main menu. View the css update in the superfish.css file on line 14. (how do I post a block of code? it limits characters...sorry I'm new at this)